# Table Width not being respected in outlook

Tags: html-table, outlook, width, html-email

I have an email message that the width of a table is being respected in all email clients except outlook (surprise).

The table should be shrinking everything under the picture header and above the picture footer to 90% like shown in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/jwestqualtrics/pen/dmWPKx

In outlook, it is not being set to 90% as shown in the below picture

[image: Outlook Version of Email, table width not respected]

Here is the portion of the code is not working.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" width="90%">
```

Where the width = 90% is the part that is not working. See the whole code in the codepen. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont understand your issue. Do you want your images in .header and .footer to scale down on mobile devices?

Comment: No, I simply want to indent the information between the header image and the footer image by 90 percent. See difference between the picture shown above and the codepen that is shown.

Comment: Use a width on the image rather than 100%